# how can I make sure that the edit text field (android) is not locked by any other thread?

Tags: android, multithreading

I have an activity to search in some remote database there is an edit text field to put your search key words. when the search complete for the first time and results retrived successfully I couldn't write in that text field as in this pic [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vhGOj.jpg).
My guess is that text field is locked by another thread so I need to verify that guess.
If any one have other thought please share it with me

thanks in advance.

Comment: Your app code is only running in one thread, unless you created additional threads.  Therefore, if another thread has it locked, it's your thread!

Answer (score 2):

Only the UI thread (main thread) of the app can manipulate UI elements.  That appears as though something has disabled the view and not re-enabled it.

Answer (score 1):

As @Larry Schiefer mentioned, only the UI thread can access UI elements. That being said, there are multiple ways to access the UI thread, such as using `runOnUiThread` or the `onPostExecute` method of an `AsyncTask`, so it is valuable to ensure that the UI is only being accessed from one source at a time. One way to do this is to implement a `Handler` for the UI, which means that all request to update the UI are posted to the `Handler` such that only the `Handler` is directly accessing the UI. You can find alot of valuable information on how to communicate with the UI here: https://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/communicate-ui.html

As a side note, it is valuable to remember that, since Java supports concurrency, any given resource could potentially be accessed by multiple sources at the same time if you are not careful with your programming. While there are a variety of strategies for protecting resources one valuable tool is to use a `Semaphore`, which essentially act like a key - no key means no access. The simple code snipped below can be used to protect a resource which may be accessed from multiple sources to ensure that it is not accessed at the same time:

```
Semaphore mySemaphore = new Semaphore(1);
mySemaphore.acquire();
// Access resource
mySemaphore.release();
```

The above snipped declares a `Semaphore` with one permit, meaning only one caller can hold it at a time, and then tries to acquire the `Semaphore` in order to access the resource; after the resource is accessed, the `Semaphore` is released. You can find more information about the `Semaphore` here: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html